# .HTACCESS - Get the parameter and rewrite

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have a url

```
website.com/v2/main-service.php?service=foo-bar
```

and I want to mask it so that the url will become

```
website.com/v2/foo-bar.html
```

I have this `.htaccess` code

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^foo-bar.html$ main-service.php?service=foo-bar
```

but it's not working. I will appreciate the help. Thank you.

Comment: That url is so ready for sql injections

Comment: I edited the question. Maybe you said it because of `index.php` but it should be `website.com`. Do you have a suggestion on how to prevent it? thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your rule is correct if you remove the "^" before foo-bar.html,
You can add variable and it give something like this :

For this url : 
http://website.com/v2/foo-bar.html

The rule :

```
RewriteRule (v[0-9])+/([a-z0-9-]+).html$ /$1/main-service.php?service=$2
```

result for php : http://website.com/v2/main-service.php?service=foo-bar

Try this here :

http://htaccess.mwl.be?share=341609bf-eda9-5a5e-92f5-a2cc3f01f921

EDIT : I change rule without index.php

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I have made a wrong line on the url and edited it.It should be `website.com` instead of `index.php`

Comment: Ok i edited my post, check it out and tell me if it's solve your issue.

Comment: It doesn't work using this url `website.com/v2/foo-bar.html`.